# Order Confirmation EMail: Thumbnails missing

Tags: shopware6

Since updating from Shopware 6.4 to 6.5.3.3 the order confirmation email does not contain thumbnails images in the list of ordered products.

The twig-variable

```
{{nestedItem.cover}}
```

is not set and the table field

```
<td>{% if nestedItem.cover is defined and nestedItem.cover is not null %}<img src="{{ nestedItem.cover.url }}" width="75" height="auto"/>{% endif %}</td>
```

remains empty.

What I checked:

Cover media is set on the product; thumbnails are OK on checkout page;
only the confirmation EMail does not contain images.

In the admin-backend (edit email templates), in the list of variables

```
order.nestedLineItems --> {% for lineItem in order.nestedLineItems %}
```

is not included.

The translation in the template

```
{% set nestedItem = lineItem %} --> nestedItem.payload.productNumber / nestedItem.cover
```

contains the productNumber, but not the cover.

Any idea?
Thanks G111

Answer (score 1):

You can find the fixtures for the original, current  order confirmation mail template [here](https://github.com/shopware/platform/tree/trunk/src/Core/Migration/Fixtures/mails/order_confirmation_mail). Check if they are up-to-date. These haven't been changed for a while, so it seems unlikely this is caused by a change in the original template.

You could try [refreshing the index](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/configuration/caches-indexes#manage-caches-indexes). However if you're seeing which image is the cover image in the administration it seems unlikely that this is the cause.

It sounds as if the association for `lineItems.cover` isn't added in the criteria for fetching the order data. However if that was the case in the core, it would mean all users would be affected, which would've been known. If you have third-party plugins installed, try deactivating them one by one to see if it resolves the issue.

Also, just to be sure, check that the latest records in the table `order_line_item` (sort by `created_at` descending) indeed have values for the `cover_id` column.

Answer (score 1):

According to Shopware it is a bug in 6.5.3.3

In Version 6.5.4.1 the thumbnails are again in the mails.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).